# Printf All Array Elements Simpler Way (50+ rows)

Tags: php, arrays

I am fetching data from an excel file which has around 50+ rows. With `print_r` i can manage to print them all at once but I need to print them out with specific format such as;

`row[0]|row[1]|row[2]...row[n] -> sampleData_A|sampleData_B|sampleData_C|...|sampleData_N`

Currently what I am doing is below;

```
foreach ($values as $row) {
    printf("%s|%s|%s|%s|...%n, $row[0], $row[1], $row[2], $row[3], $row[n]);
}
```

When this `n` goes to 50th+ row, the code readability is not good at all and I believe there is an easier way to achieve this.

What procedure should I follow to achieve easier way of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach ($values as $row) {
    echo implode("|", $row);
}
```